# No such host is known - Mass Transit - Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

This might be very basic but I am not able to get it to work for some reason.

I am using Mass transit Azure Service Bus package v 5.5.6 to connect to my service bus queue on Azure.

Following [Mass Transit documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/transports/azure-sb.html) this is how I am trying to create a bus control and start it:

```
            this.bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
            {

                var host = sbc.Host(newUri("sb://<my-servicebus-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/"), h =>
                {
                    h.SharedAccessSignature(s =>
                    {
                        s.KeyName = "<key-name>";
                        s.SharedAccessKey = "<key>"; 
                        s.TokenTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                        s.TokenScope = TokenScope.Namespace;                       
                    });

                 });
            });

            await bus.StartAsync();
```

**However it keeps throwing "No such host is known".**

at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient.SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\ApplicationSourceCode\azure-sdk-for-net\sdk\servicebus\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\src\Management\ManagementClient.cs:line 1219

I even tried : `"sb://<my-servicebus-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<my-queue-name>/"` as Host uri

*I am using Azure service bus standard tier.*

Its working fine using QueueClient in Microsot.Azure.ServiceBus.

I tried pinging the service bus uri and it does exist.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, not sure why it isn't. You could change it to use the connection string (copy it from the Azure portal) and pass it, as a string, to the Host method:

```
cfg.Host(connectionString);
```

The connection string should include the host, access key, etc. which is parsed and used to configure the host. MassTransit uses that same queue client, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. Unless you aren't running the bus in the same context as the queue client, such as behind a firewall or something that doesn't propagate DNS.

Comment: Based on the cues from your answer, I tried it on another machine and it worked like a charm. However still unsure why it does not work on the first machine, maybe DNS or firewall, although if that was the case then I expected the host name to fail even through QueueClient and ping. Anyhow, it works now and I can proceed on other machine. Thanks for your time and prompt reply.